# Where can I learn Java GUI creation

Tags: java, user-interface

Please suggest to me a website to learn Java GUI creation.

Comment: @Jazz, requires that Rover12 knows that Java-slang for GUI is "Swing".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go with [Java Swing Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/). This should introduce you to some *easy* examples of GUIs and give you some cool widgets to place with.

Also, if you're looking into buying books, I know that the [Head First](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_First_(book_series)) book series do a very good [Java Book](http://www.play.com/Books/Books/4-/578557/Head-First-Java/Product.html) which is what I first read to introduce me to it. It has a very good GUI section where you make a music player. Very well written, and in some parts humorous book. Worth the money, I'd say!

Answer (score 2):

The [Java Tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/ui/index.html) are a quite good resource to learn.

Comment: Might downvoters leave a comment as for the why?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the official Java Tutorial:  http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/

Note that this is a rather large area and may be hard to learn properly.   Don't be discouraged :)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorials/Java/Swing/1,

A whole range of tutorials submitted by users, very nice.

Answer (score 0):

I like [MIGLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) to layout (duh) my apps. But you should probably start with some basics as others already pointed out.

btw: I admit there are times when an imperative is good. But now and then a *"please"* is the way to go...

Answer (score 0):

[Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-functionality.html) is a good place for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

Try [IntelliJ IDEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA).
It's a GUI designer that can generate code.

But before you do that, read what  [AWT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Window_Toolkit) and [Swing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_%28Java%29) are, what is lightweight/heavyweight, paint/update/repaint and how layouts work.

Good luck!